# Passar valor por link

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, zend-framework-2

Preciso enviar um valor através de um link para outra página:

```
<li><a href="" onclick="getPasta()" id="icons"><?php echo $this->translate('Download');?></a></li>
```

Tentei utilizar este código para envio:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getPasta(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.post(
                    "../download/index.phtml", 
                    { pasta: "id" }
            );
        }
</script>
```

Porem não está funcionando. Aproveito também para perguntar como eu capturaria esse valor na minha página de destino, pois preciso do valor `pasta:id` esteja em uma varável PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipo assim :

```
<li><a href="../download/index.phtml?pasta=id_7" id="icons"><?php echo $this->translate('Download');?></a></li>
```

Para pegar o valor:

```
$peguei = $_GET['pasta'];
```